# Did Trump promise to bring back waterboarding?

Tags: politics, quotes, donald-trump

According to the Wikipedia article [Guantanamo Bay detention camp § President Trump's statements on the camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guantanamo_Bay_detention_camp#President_Trump's_statements_on_the_camp):

> President Donald Trump has vowed to keep the prison open and to use it to detain "bad dudes". Trump has stated, "I would bring back waterboarding, and I’d bring back a hell of a lot worse than waterboarding... Don’t tell me it doesn’t work—torture works... if it doesn’t work, they deserve it anyway, for what they’re doing to us."

The cited source leads us to a The New Yorker article [Why Obama Has Failed to Close Guantánamo](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/08/01/why-obama-has-failed-to-close-guantanamo), which states:

> Donald Trump has vowed to keep the prison open, and to “load it up with some bad dudes.” According to a leaked memo obtained by CNN, those prisoners will include American ISIS supporters—which, critics say, will likely mean American Muslims, deprived of their constitutional rights. “I would bring back waterboarding, and I’d bring back a hell of a lot worse than waterboarding,” Trump has said, adding, in other appearances, “Don’t tell me it doesn’t work—torture works,” and “If it doesn’t work, they deserve it anyway, for what they’re doing to us.”

This is unclear for me for the following reasons:

- The alleged quotation from Trump seems to be composed of at least two different statements from Trump, one coming *from a leaked memo obtained by CNN* and the other one coming from *other appearances*;
- It is unclear for me whether the part about waterboarding comes from *a leaked memo* or from *other appearances*;
- How credible is this *leaked memo*?
- Finally, the practice of composing a single statement out of a few smaller, out-of-context parts seems suspicious for me; for example, is it clear that Trump was referring to Guantanamo torture practices he had been condoning while he was saying that *torture worked* and was he referring to American ISIS supporters when he was saying that *they deserved it anyway*?

Bottom line: Has Trump's statement about torture at Guantanamo, as quoted by Wikipedia, accurately represent what Trump's has said?

Answer (score 86):

Yes, Trump has supported waterboarding and other forms of torture at various times and promised to "bring back waterboarding" during the primary.

The first quote is from a [republican primary](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/promise/1374/bring-back-waterboarding/) in New Hampshire. The video is available [here](https://youtu.be/p-9YCsaW9tc?t=28).

> "I would bring back waterboarding, and I’d bring back a hell of a lot
>   worse than waterboarding,"

As the Politifact article states, Trump has gone back and forth on the issue. During the campaign, he was a prominent supporter of torture (the quotes are accurate), but in office, Trump deferred the issue to others who are of the opinion that torture would be illegal under current law.

The [second quote](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-politics/wp/2015/11/23/donald-trump-on-waterboarding-if-it-doesnt-work-they-deserve-it-anyway/?utm_term=.b0c6911a056d) is from a campaign speech in Ohio (a video is embedded in the link).

> "Would I approve waterboarding? You bet your ass I would — in a
>   heartbeat,"

The "leaked memo" in the quote is not relevant to these public and video-taped quotes by Trump. The sentence might be a bit confusing. The claim that is attributed to this memo is that the Guantanamo prisoners that will be kept include ISIS supporters, not Trump's publicly expressed views on torture.